# Same format of struct.pack() producing different results on different computers

Tags: python, struct.pack

I am using the format as '<h4l12fl' in struct.pack() function in python. However what I noticed that in two different computers the result is different although the python version and modules are same in both computers. (The chipset in one of them is AMD and the other is Intel). Can anyone help me what to do as the intel one is producing the right results.

The code I am using is:

```
 with open(path + '.bts', 'wb') as fl:
        # write the header
        fl.write(pack(_TS_BIN_FMT,
                      [7, 8][periodic],  # 7 is not periodic, 8 is periodic
                      nz,
                      ny,
                      0,  # assuming 0 tower points below grid
                      nt,
                      dz,
                      dy,
                      dt,
                      uhub,
                      zhub,
                      z[0],
                      u_scl[0],
                      u_off[0],
                      u_scl[1],
                      u_off[1],
                      u_scl[2],
                      u_off[2],
                      len(desc_str)))
        fl.write(desc_str.encode(encoding='UTF-8'))
        # Swap the y and z indices so that fortran-order writing agrees with the file format.
        # Also, we swap the order of z-axis to agree with the file format.
        # Write the data so that the first index varies fastest (F order).
        # The indexes vary in the following order:
        # component (fastest), y-index, z-index, time (slowest).
        #fl.write(np.rollaxis(out, 2, 1).tobytes(order='F'))
        fl.write(out.tobytes(order='F'))
```

Comment: examples of the errors that you state:  the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry just added the code

Comment: That code does not produce the problem. Actually read the [mcve] link and follow the guidelines

Comment: Actually I write the file with this code. But the files created by the two computers are different although the inputs to this function are the same.

Comment: Issue ressolved. Turns out the german time stamp was the issue.